# How can I limit custom participant "state" field options relative to country?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, profile, registration, online-registration

For an event registration page, I'm using a Profile with City, Country, and State "Participant" fields. The State field is populated with states that exist outside of the specified country.

For example, the states "Abuja Federal Capital Territory" and "Zuid-Holland" are listed as options with "United States" is the selected country. Is there a way to limit state options to US states?

[image: State options]

Comment: Doesn't sound right. Once you choose the Country you should only see States from that Country. Maybe there is an you could identify via the Console on your browser. If you want to compare to another site, try https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1

Comment: Agreed with Pete - the standard behavior is to limit state/province based on country.